# Compare string to column in different dataframe r

Tags: r

I have one dataframe `df_EU` that is composed of scientists working in the EU in the following format:

```
Author ID     Country Year
A      12345  UK      2011
B      13254  Germany 2018
C      54952  Belgium 2005
D      58774  UK      2009
E      88569  Italy   2015
...
```

Then, I have another dataframe that contains scientists from the US `df_US`  in the same format. Now, what I am trying to do is to add a new column for the US dataframe in which I compare each ID in the US dataframe with all the IDs in the EU dataframe. Each time there is a match, I want a 1 to appear in the new column, for each ID that is not in the EU set, a 0.

So far, I am fairly certain that my solution should contain `mapply` and i deducted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325092/compare-character-in-column-with-string-in-another-column) that I can "load" the values for the ID numbers using:

```
mapply(function(i, j) length(grep(i, j)), df_EU$ID, df_US$ID)
```

I am, however, quite lost on how to proceed from here. I have never really worked with functions, and would therefore greatly appreciate your help! Thank you very much.

Another problem is that the scientists might appear multiple times per dataframe, as they are not listed by their unique names but by publications that have appeared in the respective region.

Comment: are these of the same dimensions with same number of 'ID's, then only the `mapply` works.

Comment: Unfortunately, the different dataframes have different number of rows. The number and names of columns are the same

Comment: Why don't you just bind them ? `dplyr::left_join(df_EU, df_US, by="ID")` or maybe `dplyr::intersect()`

Comment: Are you just looking for to see if there are any common, exact, ID's? If so, just use `%in%`:  `df_US$in_EU <- as.integer(df_US$ID %in% df_EU$ID)`. Keep in mind, this will also match `NA`'s if you have any

Comment: @Andrew that was exactly what I had been looking for! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here, we can use a `regex_fuzzy_join`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
df_US <- regex_left_join(df_US, df_EU %>%
                            select(ID), by = 'ID') %>%
             mutate(EU_migration = !is.na(ID.y))
```

Comment: do I need to assign this somehow or does this generate a whole new dataframe for me? Because I tried to assign the additional column this function generated in my head with df_US$EU_migration <- (your solution) but it gave me `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, eu_mig, value = list(X1 = c(0, 1, 2,  : 
  replacement has 9298 rows, data has 9202`

Comment: @P.Weyh  If you want a column to be named 'EU_migration`, then `df_US <- regex_left_join(df_US, df_EU %>%
                            select(ID), by = 'ID') %>%
        mutate(EU_migration= !is.na(ID.y))`

Comment: Okay, I tried that, but for some reason the code was counting some hits several times (1-8 times). If it helps, I could give you the data, but it is too big to be posted here with `dput`. Thank you for your guidance!

Comment: @P.Weyh  Only way it could count several times is when theere are duplicates for thee 'by' column matches in each dataset.

Comment: shoot, you are right, I forgot to add that to the question! I am sorry, yes, the scientists might appear multiple times in the EU dataset, once or several times per year.

Comment: But I think Andrew solved my problem in the comment for the question. Nevertheless, I am very thankful for your help! :)

Comment: @P.Weyh  I used `regex_left_join` only bacause of your `grep`.  if it is exact match, then `%in%` is more appropriate

Comment: oh, I see. In that case, I am very sorry for having posted misleading information in my question!

Comment: @P.Weyh  It's okay.  with `dplyr`, it would be `df_US <- df_US %>% mutate(EU_migration =  as.integer(ID %in% df_EU$ID))`